Itemize and minted environment height problem inside minipage
I'm having some problems setting the height of the minipage on the left, in the example code below.
I've tried many suggestions I found on this forum (\vspace{0cm}, \raggedbottom, \raggedright, setting the height in cm explicitely,etc)
So, far nothing has worked...
Here's the minimal working example:
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}


\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
        \frametitle{Title}
        \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
    \small
    Some textt asdas da sdasd asdasdddddddddddddsssssssss
    sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{0.6\textwidth}
            \centering
            \footnotesize
            \begin{minted}[
                bgcolor=LightGray,
                linenos,
                fontsize=\footnotesize
            ]{python}
some code 
some code
some code
            \end{minted}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some item: description
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \footnotesize
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{path/to/picture}
            \caption{some picture}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}


\end{document}



Your code does not compile for anybody but you.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz why?

We don't have access to external files like your image.

You could use Top aligned beamer columns:
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}


\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{The \texttt{Figure.subplot\_mosaic} Method}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{The \texttt{Axes} object}
    \framesubtitle{Adding a grid of \texttt{Axes}: 
    The \texttt{Figure.subplot\_mosaic} Method}
    \small
    Some textt asdas da sdasd asdasdddddddddddddsssssssss
    sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
            \centering
            \footnotesize
            \begin{minted}[
                bgcolor=LightGray,
                linenos,
                fontsize=\footnotesize
            ]{python}
some code 
some code
some code
            \end{minted}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item some item: description
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
%            \centering
            \begin{figure}
            \footnotesize
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
            \caption{some picture}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\end{document}



Thanks for your answer. I realized that the problem is alleviated by using \begin{figure} \includegraphics{...} \end{figure} in my code.

@Anoldmaninthesea. You can add \vskip-0.2cm (or whatever value suites you) between the minted environment and the itemize

Thanks SamCarter ;)

@Anoldmaninthesea. You're welcome!

You don't want to set the height of the minipages and the left one should be moved a bit to the right, if you want to show the line numbers.
I visually gaged the vertical space above the minted environment and added also a zero vertical space in the minipage on the right in order to set the anchor.
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\small

Some textt asdas da sdasd asdasdddddddddddddsssssssss
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

\begin{figure}
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
\begin{minted}[
  bgcolor=LightGray,
  linenos,
  fontsize=\footnotesize
]{python}
some code 
some code
some code
\end{minted}

\begin{itemize}
  \item some item: description
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{some picture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Many thanks egreg ;)
